# Удаление ссылки якоря из адресной строки

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть ли способ убрать из адресной строки ссылку  якорь `#anchor`?

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-decoration:none;
}
menu{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:#fff;
  line-height:50px;
  outline:1px solid #eee;
}
menu span{
  position:relative;
}
menu span:after{
  content:'';
  border:5px solid transparent;
  border-top:5px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  right:-14px; top:48%;
}
menu a{
  color:blue;
}
menu .preview{
  background:#fff;
  outline:1px solid #eee;
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  padding:0 18px;
  position:relative;
}
.preview .block{
  position:absolute;
  top:51px; left:0;
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  background:#fff;
  display:none;
  outline:1px solid #eee;
}
.preview:hover .block{
  display:block;
}
.block .content{
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  margin:15px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content .left,.right{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
}
.content .left{
  width:30%;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
}
.content .left_menu {
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0;
  left:15px; right:0;
  outline:1px solid #eee;
  width:90%;
  height:300px;
  margin:auto;
}
.left_menu p{
  background:#eee;
  margin:0 0 1px 0;
  padding-left:3px;
}
.left_menu p a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.content .right{
  width:70%;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
}
.content .right .right_preview{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0;
  left:0; right:0;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.news{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#a{
  background:red;
}
#b{
  background:blue;
}
#c{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
    <menu> 
    <div class="preview"> 
      <span><a href="">Примеры</a></span>
      <div class="block"> 
         <div class="content"> 
           <div class="left">
             <div class="left_menu"> 
                <p><a id="clear_anchor" href="#c">Примеры скриптов</a></p>
                <p><a id="clear_anchor" href="#b">Новинки видео</a></p>
                <p><a id="clear_anchor" href="#a">Последние посты</a></p>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="right"> 
             <div class="right_preview"> 
                 <div id="a" name="" class="news"></div>
                 <div id="b" name="" class="news"></div>
                 <div id="c" name="" class="news"></div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</menu>
```

Вот это оставляет след в  адресной  строке броузера а именно `#a,#b,#c` и это надо убрать.
window.location.hash пробовал :

```js
<script>
  window.hashName = window.location.hash;
  window.location.hash = '';

  $(window).load(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(window.hashName).offset().top}, 2000);
      return false;});
   });

</script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var buttons = document.getElementById('clear_anchor');

            buttons.onclick = function() {
                history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
            };
        }
 </script>
```

что приводило к тому что вообще переставал работать `html`

Comment: Я добивался вот это : https://geyanpeaple.github.io/hoverJqueryMenu/

Answer (score 4):

Можете просто вызвать `window.location.hash = '';`

Может остаться `#`. Если это вас не устраивает, то можно попробовать сделать так:

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname +
        window.location.pathname + window.location.search
```

Но это может привести к перезагрузке страницы.

Либо используя регулярные выражения:

```
var url = window.location.toString(); 
url = url.replace(/#anchor/,''); 
window.location = url;
```

*[отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129178/remove-anchor-but-not-arguments-via-javascript)

---

Убрать все до якоря можно так:

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + window.location.hash;
```

или так:

```
window.location.pathname = '';
```

Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Так ведь написано _убрать ссылку **до** якоря_, а не **после**.

Comment: @Regent, упс, сейчас отредактирую.

Comment: все способы НЕ сработали ! Я дополню щас

Comment: я добивался вот это https://geyanpeaple.github.io/hoverJqueryMenu/

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
function deleteAnchor() {
    var str = document.location.toString();
    document.location = str.substring(0, str.lenght - str.indexOf('#'));
}
```

И потом просто вызывать когда необходимо удалить якорь

```
<input type="button" value="Удалить якорь" onclick="deleteAnchor()">
```

Comment: Brik Vadim  я уже сделал : https://geyanpeaple.github.io/hoverJqueryMenu/